# Import data from excel sheet with new columns in CRM 2013 Online

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I previously imported data from an excel sheet into CRM that had around a dozen columns in it. At that time some of those columns were empty. Now that excel sheet has been updated to include values in those previously empty columns. 
How do I import only those newly updated columns in excel sheet to update their respective CRM records? Is their a way of importing them without creating duplicates and anyway messing up the records in CRM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One to do would be to run an advanced find with the new columns plus any columns that you would need to identify the rows. Next, export to Excel all of the rows from the page and check the box to make the rows importable (see attached screenshot)[image: screenshot].

Finally, put the data for the columns into the appropriate columns and then import the spreadsheet.

This is probably the best way to update existing records through the data import utility.

Comment: Although this will only work if have less records then the maximum CRM page size which is 200.

Comment: Make sure to include the owner column to prevent accidentally setting the ownership of these records to the user performing the reimport.  That way the import process will retain the existing record ownership.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the data being exported and added to the Excel file is under the 8 MB size limit, you could get all records exported if you marked the "Static worksheet with records from all pages in the current view" while also keeping the "Make this data available for re-importing by including required column headings" checked as seen in the screen shot in the answer here.