# Bulk update record in CRM Online

Tags: excel, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I asked a similar yet slightly different question before [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810274/import-data-from-excel-sheet-with-new-columns-in-crm-2013-online/25815868#25815868) I am using CRM 2013 Online and there are couple of thousand records in it. The records we created by an import of excel sheet data that came from a SQL database.

There were some fields in each record in which there was no data when the first import from excel was made. The system works in such a way that the excel sheet is updated from the SQL database periodically, and that data then needs to be imported in CRM Online. As far as I know and mentioned in the shared link, you can only bulk update the records in CRM by first importing the data from CRM to Excel and then reimporting the same sheet back to excel.

Is there a way to bulk update the records in CRM Online if I get data from the client in an Excel sheet?

Right now I compare their excel sheet to my exported excel sheet and make the required changes. It works well for small amount of records but it is infeasible for bulk record update. Any ideas?

2) Or is their a way to compare two excel sheets and make sure that if you copy columns from one sheet to another, the data in the column ends up in the right rows?

Comment: http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2013/08/01/updating-records-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm/

I found this, another option that addresses my issue. But I want some opinions on the way described here.

Comment: Regarding the PowerObjects blog post, this could be an efficient way to update records.  It's going to end up adding more data in Microsoft CRM with the addition of a new entity, but that can be handled through bulk delete jobs to clean up the records after they are imported.  Testing it would be the best way to find out how it works for your scenario.

Comment: What approach did you decide on?

Comment: Well I added the new records in a test/dummy entity. Used a workflow that was associated with this test entity that ran on new records, matched the ID in test entity with the record ID in my actual entity. This way you can add new records and update the old ones

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue with updating records from a CSV file. It is true that SSIS is one way. To solve our problem, I created a .NET executable application which is scheduled to execute once per week. The .NET application does the following

1. Connects to the organisation
2. Imports all records from the excel
   spreadsheet using a pre-existing data map in CRM organisation
3. Runs a duplicate detection rule (already existing in the CRM organisation)and brings back all duplicates
4. Sorts through each duplicate and stores the guid into 2 arrays: list of original records and list of newly imported records (based on created date of record)
5. Performs a merge of the old data on the record with the new data (this is
   performed through the CRM2013 SDK MergeResponse class
6. Now that the original records have been updated with the new data from the
   spreadsheet, delete the duplicate records which have just been
   created and then made inactive due to the use of MergeResponse class in step 5 . (for us, we were updating contact info, but wanted the
   orginal contact to stay in CRM because they will have cases etc
   related to that contact's GUID)

If you want to go down this route, I suggest looking at the example on the MS website which uses the CRM SDK (\CRM 2013 SDK\SDK\SampleCode\CS\DataManagement\DataImport\ImportWithCreate.cs). That is the sample code which I used to create the web service.

Answer (score 0):

As you have thousands of records then I guess that `SSIS` Package is the best option for you. its very efficient in such scenorios.

Comment: I have tried using SQL SSIS but it does not work with CRM Online. Others such as Scribe are expensive. Do you know any good ones?

Comment: Kingsway soft make a SSIS component that interacts with CRM both online and on premise. Its free to use if you don't want to run it outside of visual studio

Comment: SSIS works with CRM online, follow this article http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2012/11/integrating-crm-2011-using-sql.html

Comment: This one is also helpful http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2014/01/insert-update-and-delete-records-in-crm.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I would use:

1. Create a Duplication Detection Rule under **Settings** > **Data Management**
2. Download the Import Template
3. Adjust your source system to generate the spreadsheet in that particular format

Depending on the frequency of your updates I'd look into [CRM web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151038.aspx) to import your data.

Comment: Kye, what do you mean by point 3? Can you elaborate it a little more.

Comment: You mentioned that you use SQL to generate the spreadsheet. I'd change the SQL so that the column names and value match what CRM is expecting. That might save you some time if you need to do the upload on a regular basis.